# Meteor.call does not wait for the result

Tags: javascript, meteor

The Async callback in Meteor.call does not wait for the result from the Meteor.method.This is the code.

```
Meteor.call("fetchData",function (err,res) {
        if (err){
            console.log("error ", err);
        }else {
            console.log("success ", res);
            return res;
        }
    });//calling this from onRendered of client/somejs.js
```

Here is the method

```
fetchData :function(){
        HTTP.call("POST","http://localhost:8080",{
            data:'{"apple":"grape"}'
        },function (err,res) {
            if (err){
                console.log("error ", err);
            }else {
                console.log("success ", res);
                return res;
            }
        })
    }//Server/methods.js
```

When Meteor.call is triggered,i get a log on the Server as `success` with its result.
On the client i get `success undefined` .
The call on the client does not wait for the result.Also i tried Fibers and Synchronous execution on the server.It does not work for me.In this case a publish is blocked(i guess due to the API call).

Another thing is that i tried the same with a DB query instead of API call.That works fine.I get the result from the Method.

Where am i going wrong.Help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sanjith.

You were on the right path with futures. By default, Meteor's methods are async, so some "waiting" mechanism is needed on the client. For this, I'd recommend either using Meteor.wrapAsync or Promises. Here are two detailed explanations on implementing both:

https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/synchronous-methods/#tmc-using-wrapasync

https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/promise-based-modules/#tmc-calling-our-promise-based-module-from-the-client

The second link is more focused on structuring your code using promises, but gives a nice demo of how to call a method that relies on a Promise's response.

Comment: but why does the same work in case of a DB query.?I had a method which checks if the username exists already.This worked fine and i was receiving the result on the client's Meteor.call.Btw will check out the links.I am pretty new to JS.